Can one prove that $\forall x (x\notin x)$ implies the axiom of regularity?
The axiom of regulatity is equivalent to the statement that there are no downward infinite membership chains. Such a result implies that no set contains itself. I was wondering if, covnersely, the statement $\forall x(x\notin x)$ implies the axiom of regularity (assuming the rest of the axioms of ZFC).

No, it is not equivalent. For instance it’s consistent that there are double Quine atoms ($x\ne y$ with $x\in y\in x$) but no Quine atoms (sets with $x\in x$.).
